# Create own web documentation from React Native app

Tags: react-native, documentation, react-styleguidist

Is there a way to create a documentation (like reactnative.dev / react-styleguidist) for a React Native app?

Comment: Do you mean in React Native or for React Native?

Comment: I have a React Native app and I would like to create its documentation accessible from a web browser

Answer (score 2):

You could use "react-styleguidist" or "storybook" but using "react-native-web" to render the components.

This will not work for all usecases(especially with Android/iOS only components), but hopefully it should cover most of the use cases in a component library.

Storybook has a guide on how to deploy these docs:
https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/deploy/